# Pivot table calculate field based on grouped values

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

after years of quietly learning from this site I've finally hit a question who's answer I cannot seem to find on StackOverflow...

---

I have a pivot table that needs to calculate Net Promoter Score from several groups within a population.

Net promoter score is calculated like so:

```
[% of Population that give 9 or 10/10] - [% of Population that give 1 to 6/10]
```

Each individual record in my source data can only have a single Score of between 1 and 10:

```
RAW DATA:
Date (dd/mm)    Country    Type         Score (1-10)    NPS Category
01/05           US         Order enq.   9               Promoter
13/05           US         Check-out    5               Detractor
28/05           US         Order enq.   7               Passive
```

So, with help from the answers below I've added a column to categorise each individual into the Promoter (9 or 10), Passive (7 or 8) and Detractor (1 to 6) groups based on that score: [screenshot of raw data](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9369383/9228693/8d08fb12-4111-11e5-91ad-aabfc710f1b7.png) (with sensitive items hidden).

All that remains now is:
How can I create a calculated 'NPS' column like the one shown in my (rudimentary) representation of a pivot table below that takes the Detractor value from the Promoter value?

```
D = Detractor group
Pa = Passive group
Pr = Promoter group


      |     Order enquiry    |      Check-out      |
      | D    Pa   Pr   NPS   |  D    Pa   Pr   NPS |
-------------------------------------------------- |
GB    |                      |                     |
  May |  0    0  100    100  | 30    20    50   20 |
  Jun | 10   30   60     50  | 35    35    60   25 |
  Jul | 30   20   50     20  | 40    10    40    0 |
US    |                      |                     |
  May | 45   15   40    - 5  | 50    10    40  -10 |
  Jun | 40   30   30    -10  | 40    30    30  -10 |
  Jul |  5   35   60     55  | 20    40    40   20 |
```

My attempt at a calculated column can be seen in this [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9369383/9221907/bf1f698c-40e5-11e5-9409-6ce82ae2762f.png). This results in an error and of course I haven't managed to convert the NPS counts into percentages yet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be my suggestion to create a new column in the source that calculates `D`, `Pa`,`Pr` by a formula.

You can now create the % for these values in the pivot. The NPS column can either be calculated after pivoting the output field, or by creating a pivot-column formula in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The trouble is, NPS can't be calculated for a single individual (or single row in the source) because it is the proportion of all Promoter individuals minus the proportion of all Detractor individuals in a population.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how your data is laid out, or what exactly you're asking. From what I can see, you need to add a column in your raw data table, which says something like

```
=COUNTIFS(UniqueID,MyUniqueID,Score,">=9")-COUNTIFS(UniqueID,MyUniqueID,Score,"<=6")
```

Then another column that says

```
=IF(NetPromoter>=9,"Pr",IF(NetPromoter>=7,"Pa","D"))
```

And then in your pivot table you add the Classification as a new subcolumn, and add the NPS as the Average of your NPS column, or something like that.

Please show your data if you want the formulas changed to meet your actual range/variable terms.

Comment: I see, include a Classification column to the raw data to determine whether each individual was a Promoter, Passive or Detractor and then the pivot table wouldn't need to do the grouping. That would just leave the Calculated field to find the populations' NPS... I'll give that a go.

Comment: @PangolinPaws Exactly. Better to do the math in the raw data tab, and then incorporate that as a new column for your pivot table. I left the terms of the formulas above as descriptions; you will need to either name the appropriate columns as I have them there or convert them to Cell references. Without your raw data in the Question I can't be more specific.

Comment: @Martijn and Grade I now realise both of you were suggesting the same thing, so thank you for your help. Sadly, I am still stuck, although the  NPS category is now formulated in my raw data, how do I get the calculated field to take the Detractors from the Promoters (I'll worry about % later)? [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9369383/9221907/bf1f698c-40e5-11e5-9409-6ce82ae2762f.png)

Comment: @PangolinPaws **Update your question to include descriptions of your raw data tab**. Without that it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Apologies, you asked for that before. It's now better described & screenshots are included (the order is slightly different as I have hidden sensitive fields such as customer details etc.).